# LocationManager exception

Tags: android

I'm trying to make LocationManager work and get weird security exception. When I run code:

```
this.lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
this.lm.setTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I get following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
        at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.setTestProviderStatus(ILocationManager.java:981)
        at android.location.LocationManager.setTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.java:1107)
```

And I have following in manifest file:

```
<application android:label="IDATT" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<uses-permission .../>` goes outside the `<application .../>` tag.

See [Structure of the Manifest File](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct).

Comment: That doesn't make difference. I tried both ways - when debug on emulator I get this exception

Comment: The same exception as before?

Comment: Same line but no, different exception:
 Provider "gps" unknown

Comment: @katit a different exception means that your original problem is fixed and you now have a new problem.

Comment: agreed. Will post new question

Answer (score 1):

On your device, go to Settings -> Applications -> Development and make sure that "Allow Mock Location" is checked.