# LocationManager exception Provider "gps" unknown

Tags: android

This is related to my own question here:
[LocationManager exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543822/locationmanager-exception)

Now that I have no permission issue - same line of code gives me exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider "gps" unknown
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1251)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
        at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.setTestProviderEnabled(ILocationManager.java:942)
```

EDIT:
From what I read - I need to use Eclipse or DDMS. But I use IntelliJ 
How do I mock locations using my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that setTestProviderStatus deprecated. Googling and searching didn't help. Some information from book gave me clue that those absolete. Instead, need to mock locations using DDMS when using emulator or device. So, I tried go that route and it seems to be working.