# Provider "gps" unknown exception while trying to removeTestProvider

Tags: android, unit-testing, gps

Does anyone know why or has resolved this issue I'm having:

```
09-21 11:49:45.007: WARN/System.err(22711): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider "gps" unknown
09-21 11:49:45.007: WARN/System.err(22711):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1251)
09-21 11:49:45.007: WARN/System.err(22711):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
09-21 11:49:45.007: WARN/System.err(22711):     at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.removeTestProvider(ILocationManager.java:889)
09-21 11:49:45.007: WARN/System.err(22711):     at android.location.LocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.java:1008)
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544386/locationmanager-exception-provider-gps-unknown/5544944#5544944) does not solve since I don't even get into the deprecated method. It fails first while trying to remove the provider.

Is this a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4036)?

**EDIT:**

In my code I check the existence of the provider "gps" in the list:

```
 final String TEST_PROVIDER =  LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;    // "gps" 
 if (mLocationManager.getProvider(TEST_PROVIDER) != null) {
      mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(TEST_PROVIDER);
 }
```

Weird thing is that it **was** working before.

Comment: It looks you're trying to remove the 'gps' provider when its not in your list of location providers.

Comment: But I get the same error if I remove this line at `LocationManager.addTestProvider()` and after at `LocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled()`. Moreover before removing, I have an if statement to check if it is in the list and it doesn't return null!

Answer (score 2):

I think **removeTestProvider**(TEST_PROVIDER) only works ***after*** you've called **addTestProvider**(TEST_PROVIDER).